# Are there any railroads in Antarctica?

Tags: trains, factoids, train-stations, antarctica

I am wondering if there are any railroads in Antarctica. Maybe on research stations, even those shorter than 1km?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there aren't. But could you clarify how this question is related to travel, in the sense described in the [help centre](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: I don't see why this question is off-topic. Perhaps it could have been worded better, but I am seeing an implied question of "I want to ride trains around the world. Are there any trains in Antarctica that I might be able to ride?" in there. Perhaps the question could be reworded as such and get reopened. It's a really interesting question and one I never actually considered!

Comment: This is a fascinating question and if it's off topic then we need to change the list of topics.

Comment: This would make a great example question for the Railways & Railroads proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94245/railways-railroads

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There are very few mentions of railways in Antarctica. According to [this webpage](https://sinfin.net/railways/world/antarctica.html) by Glyn Williams, a train enthusiast, there used to be one railway in the French Dumont d'Urville station, used on a very short distance to transport supplies.

On the same page and on [some others](http://www.railwaysofthefarsouth.co.uk/11cwhaling.html), there are mentions of multiple places in the far South with former railways. For example, we can see pictures of an abandoned locomotive on the South Georgia island from [a very well documented website](http://www.railwaysofthefarsouth.co.uk/11acamberrailway.html):

[image: abandoned loco on South Georgia island]

Interestingly, the carrying of the supplies on the continent is assured by long convoys that really look like trains (on snow). You can check out [this video](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x1of69_le-raid-de-dumont-d-urville-a-conco_tech) or that website:

[image: sled trains]

Comment: I don't know whether running rails up the jetty really counts...

Comment: @RoryAlsop why wouldn't it? The OP specified that short lines were acceptable.

Comment: +1, this works for me. I'd be interested in knowing if any remnants were still visible.

Comment: By the way, the man Dumont d'Urville after whom [the station in Antarctica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dumont_d%27Urville_Station) is named, died in a train accident in France, Europe.

Comment: Judging by this photo, I think it might be the passage that goes through the rocky formation, but it's possible that it's onlt a walkway. It seems that most of the hauling is done by truck. http://www.centrescientifique.mc/medias/images/content/000DSC_8773R.jpg

Comment: They look like trains, and they in fact *are* trains, in the sense of a series of (possibly interconnected) vehicles.  But the vehicles are not rail vehicles (they are on runners, which are like skis or the blades of an ice skate), and there is no railroad.